# Can not save pyplot histogram

Tags: matplotlib

I am trying to save a pyplot generated histogram . But when i try to save this it gives me an error `savefig() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given`. How to overcome this error?

Here is my code:

```
dir1=r"C:\Users\USER\Handcrafted dataset\histogram"
for i,img in enumerate(images1):
    plt.figure(figsize=(5,5))
    plt.hist(img.ravel(),256,[0,256])
    plt.savefig(dir1+"\\"+str(i)+".jpg",img)
    plt.show()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just remove `img` and try using and also comment out `plt.show()`. Since you are creating a new figure every time, I do not see why you need `img`

```
plt.savefig(dir1+"\\"+str(i)+".jpg")
# plt.show()
```